# xquery doc() function expensiveness

Tags: basex

I did expect that the doc() function should have a very low cost even in larger databases, but it turns out it does not.

Or am I doing the query wrong all along? The `ia:if-doc-available()` is making the `doc()` call, because the built-in `doc-available()` is throwing an *'..yields no doc error..'*.

```
import module namespace ia = 'http://my.tld/ia'; 
let $__result__ := (let $locTpl := <Item><Location><Province /><PostalCode /></Location></Item> 
    let $items := (for $item in collection('item_MyCar')/node() 
        let $location := ia:if-doc-available(concat('rootnamespace/item_Location/', $item/Location/@Id), $locTpl)/node()
        where not($item/@IsDeleted='True') 
        order by $item/Updated/text() descending 
    return <Item>{$item}{$location}</Item>)[position() = 1 to 6]
return <Results>{$items}</Results>) 
return <Result Count="{count($__result__/node())}">{$__result__}</Result>
```

this way I'm better off of course, but still  slow for a path only doc() joining:

```
import module namespace ia = 'http://my.tld/ia'; 
let $__result__ := (let $locTpl := <Item><Location><Province /><PostalCode /></Location></Item> 
    let $items := (for $item in collection('item_MyCar')/node() 
        where not($item/@IsDeleted='True') 
        order by $item/Updated/text() descending 
    return <Item>{$item}{ia:if-doc-available(concat('rootnamespace/item_Location/', $item/Location/@Id), $locTpl)/node()}</Item>)[position() = 1 to 6]
return <Results>{$items}</Results>) 
return <Result Count="{count($__result__/node())}">{$__result__}</Result>
```

the custom ia:if-doc-available() function:

```
declare function ia:if-doc-available
  ( $arg as xs:string?,
  $value as item()* )  as item()* {

    try {
      doc($arg)
    } catch * {
      $value
    }
};
```

Comment: If you use BadeX, you may want to have a look at the functions in the database module (db:open, db:exists,… http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Database_Module).

Comment: Yes I know the db: module. I guess you suggest me to use db:open-id() in this case? But won't that call just translate the internal id to the path of the document, and ultimately end up as a doc() query? Thanks

Comment: With db:open, you can specify two arguments: the name of your databse and the path to your document. I’m not sure what your fn:doc actually does, because it will only work in BaseX if a single document is your in your database. I assume that `rootnamespace` is the name of your second database? For further discussion, feel free to write to the base-talk mailing list.

Comment: `fn:doc()` works like `db:open()` but only with 1 arg and it is xquery spec. I guess one will be just an alias for the other in basex. `rootnamespace` might contain the dbname in it, but not a must if: [`DEFAULTDB: True`](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Options#DEFAULTDB). However thanks so far, I will write to the mailing list.